# Random Spawning along X and Y axis

Tags: swift, axis, cgrect

I am using CGRect to contain my spawning nodes within an location, which is below-

```
func CGRectMake(_ x: 90, _ y: 360, _ width: 260, _ height: 466) -> CGRect
```

My problem now is, I'm not sure how to spawn the nodes within the location with a random x and y axis? Should I use arc4random? Or is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

arc4random would be ok.

Use it like that :

```
let rect = CGRectMake(x: 90, y: 360, width: 260, height: 466)
let x = rect.origin.x + CGFloat(arc4random()) % rect.size.width
let y = rect.origin.y + CGFloat(arc4random()) % rect.size.height
let randomPoint = CGPointMake(x, y)
```

Also, you should note that if you have reverse Y axis, you should use `-` instead of `+` in y line.

Comment: Thank you! One question though, it says there is an error - Cannot invoke '+" with an argument list of type '(CGFloat, $T10). Is there any many of fixing this?

Comment: Just cast arc4random to CGFloat, I missed that as I dont have a compiler in a web browser :)

Comment: Sorry i'm new to this, so I just change the  + arc4random  to  +CGFloat?

Comment: Thankyou, no errors! One problem though it spawns the skspritenode at the right bottom hand corner, is that something I have put in my code?

Comment: It is the matter of anchor point. If you set the anchor point to the center of the node, it will spawn with `randomPoint` as its center, maybe default anchor point is the right bottom, so thats why it spawns alongside it.

Comment: To change the anchor so the randomPoint is its centre is it (0.5,0.5)?

Comment: I dont use sprite kit in daily life and dont know if anchor point is normalized there or not, but if it is, then yes it should be (0.5, 0.5)